# How to call a function inside the xml

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to call function with params within `text` property `$parents['Page'].someFunc(itemProp)` and nothing happens.
How do that?

```
<Repeater items="{{ myItems }}">
    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <Label text="{{ $parents['Page'].someFunc(itemProp) }}"/>
    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

If it's impossible, then what about case, when `someFunc()` is converter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature named [converters](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#using-converters-in-bindings), Your `someFunc` should be defined as a converter either in the bindingContext or in the application module if you want to reuse it in different pages, then you may call it from XML.

```
<Repeater items="{{ myItems }}">
  <Repeater.itemTemplate>
    <Label text="{{ itemProp, itemProp | someFunc }}"/>
  </Repeater.itemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```